# Reading the BitBucket API with Authentication for a Private Repository in C#.net

Tags: c#, api, bitbucket

I've been trying for a few days to get the BitBucket API to work for me, but have come to a grinding halt when it comes to getting it to work for a private repository with authentication (with the issues set as private, when they're set to public and no authentication is needed it all works fine)

Code sample is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebProxy prox = new WebProxy("ProxyGoesHere");
        prox.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        var address = "repositories/UserFoo/SlugBar/issues/1";
        var repCred = new CredentialCache();

        repCred.Add(new Uri("https://api.bitbucket.org/"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("UserFoo", "PassBar"));


        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = repCred;

        client.Proxy = prox;
        client.BaseAddress = "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/";
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        client.QueryString.Add("format", "xml");

        Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString(address));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem recently, and I found two different solutions.

First, vanilla .net with `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`:
*(this came from an answer here at Stack Overflow, but unfortunately I can't find the link anymore)*

```
string url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/your_username/your_repo/issues/1";
var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("your_username" + ":" + "your_password"));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);

using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Or, if you want to do the same with less code, you can use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/");
client.Authenticator =
    new HttpBasicAuthenticator("your_username", "your_password");
var request = new RestRequest("repositories/your_username/your_repo/issues/1");
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string json = response.Content;
```

---

*By the way, I decided to use the* `HttpWebRequest` *solution for my own application.

I'm writing a small tool to clone all my Bitbucket repositories (including the private ones) to my local machine. So I just make **one** single call to the Bitbucket API to get the list of repositories.

And I didn't want to include another library in my project just to save a few lines of code for this one single call.*

Comment: HttpWebRequest will only send credentials if your request results in a HTTP 401 Unauthorized response. This will result in "two requests per request": a 401, and a 200. (aside: It's also supposed to match the realm in the 401 response, but it appears Microsoft chose to ignore that part of RFC2617.) There is a poorly-named PreAuthenticate property, which will save you the extraneous request/response, but only on subsequent requests, after the first 401-200. Mostly this is harmless, but it looks like bitbucket will never issue a 401, so you need to do it "by hand".

Comment: @jbinto: can you elaborate a bit more on that? I don't know much about HTTP internals, so I'm not sure if what you pointed out is a big problem for me. As I said, I'm using HttpWebRequest exactly as in the example in my answer. Can I improve this / is there a better way to send authentication via HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Excellent! It's a shame BB API documentation says nothing about basic auth. BTW this gives a compile error, change RestResponse response to var response.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you could use [Bitbucket.Cloud.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bitbucket.Cloud.Net/):

1. get a token, for example with using [Flurl.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/):

```cs
    var uvalue = "your_username OR consumer_key";// see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html
    var pvalue = "your_password OR consumer_secret";// see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html
    var urlAccessToken = "https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/" + "access_token";
    var response = await urlAccessToken
                                       .WithBasicAuth(uvalue, pvalue)
                                       .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new
                                       {
                                           grant_type = "client_credentials"
                                       })
                                       .ReceiveJson().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var token = response.access_token;

    // Do something with your authenticated client.
```

then, using retrieved token,

```
var oauth = new Bitbucket.Cloud.Net.Common.Authentication.OAuthAuthentication(token);
var bitbucket = new Bitbucket.Cloud.Net.BitbucketCloudClient("https://api.bitbucket.org/", oauth);
//your workspace name is UserFoo
//returns list of Bitbucket.Cloud.Net.Models.v2.Repository
var list = await bitbucket.GetWorkspaceRepositoriesAsync("<your workspace name>").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WebClient is still possible, you just have to manually create the Authorization header like in the Christian Specht's answer:

```
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("your_username" + ":" + "your_password"));
client.Headers[ HttpRequestHeader.Authorization ] = "Basic " + credentials);
```