# authenticating with username and password through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, jsonp

Does anyone have any suggestions for why I'm still receiving at 403 error with the following block of code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jeffreycwitt/privaterepository/tags",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    password: "password",
    username: "username",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function
      (returndata){
        $.each(returndata, function(key, value){
          console.log(key)
    });
});
```

I'm trying to retrieve information from a private repository hosted on bitbucket using their api. The following code works on a public repository. But I can't get the request to authenticate on a private repository despite the fact that I'm passing the correct username and password with jquery settings "keys".

Is there something wrong with my code or does bitbucket need to clarify how they want to receive the username and password values. (I've contacted them directly and they will only help me get access through "curl" - which I can do with:

```
curl --user username:password https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jeffreycwitt/privaterepository/tags
```

But this doesn't help when I trying to access the info through ajax. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: what language are you using on server side ? , you do authentication from server , if you want you can make ajax request to your server, then server to server auth .  Were you really planning on leaving the username and password right there in HTML?

Comment: no -- once i get this to work -- I'll do a separate ajax call to a php script that contains the password and username -- do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: this is how you do it in c# - you can convert to PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696314/reading-the-bitbucket-api-with-authentication-for-a-private-repository-in-c-net

Comment: you can't send a username and password with a jsonp request for the same reason you cant send a username and password when including a .js file with `<script></script>`

Comment: What about with this (which I've tried) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ $.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});

Comment: as long as the datatype isn't jsonp, you can do it.

Comment: I don't understand why an api would require a username and password while offering a jsonp response. That doesn't make any sense. You can't call it from javascript that way. Maybe it's just included because it was easier to include it than to not include it.

Comment: Well, I've finally made this work using a php script -- but not in jquery. The important thing to do is add an "authorization header" but it seems that you can't do this with jsonp and jquery. Thanks to @scott selby for the C# example which ultimately led me to a solution. Here's the php code that I'm using to access a private repo in bitbucket: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13612654/731085

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that an Authorization Header is needed, which can't be done with jquery and jsonp.

See this link for how I solved my problem with a php script:  stackoverflow.com/a/13612654/731085